# AngularJS - How to make a button inside an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've made the next html code -

```
    <a  class="list-group-item">
       <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
 <p class="btn btn-info"  href="javascript:;" ng-click="onclick(alert('Hello world!'));">Hi world</p>
    </a>
```

How can I make the

with the 'btn' class be clickable? (meaning see the hello word alert)

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: what's the issue with just using a button element? Is "onclick" an actual function in your controller?

Comment: The thing is that when pressing on the <p> which is a button - it recognized it as pressing on the anchor tag and not pressing on the button

Comment: Why do you need an href on a <p> element? Why do you have an ancor list?

Answer (score 0):

From your sample it looks like you're trying to use an anchor element to have a list of text and following buttons?  Why not just put the ng-click on the Anchor element and apply the bootstrap class of btn to that?

I do believe the issue you have with your sample is that the anchor is catching the click event as opposed to the nest

element, as they're not meant to be used as containers.

Comment: a click on the the anchor tag is doing one thing - and a click on the button that nested insdie it should do a different thing

Comment: Yeah, what I'm trying to say is that's not really how you should be using anchor elements.  They should be the lowest level interaction element in any html tree. So you can either style the anchors to look like buttons, or put them inside an button/input. 

You can have both the ng-click and the text on one anchor element though without embedding a further two <p> elements.  :)

Hope this helps!